# Python indentation level of if else

Tags: python

I'm writing a prime number checker. This is my code:

```
for num in range(10):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
            else:
                print(num)
```

And the result is:

```
3
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
9
```

I found out that if I remove one indentation level of `else` such as:

```
for num in range(10):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(num)
```

the result is correct

```
2
3
5
7
```

Here is the real question. Shouldn't `else` be at the same indentation level as `if`? I am confused now.

Comment: If else should always be at the same level if there is one. In your case your else block is not aligned with the first if block. Using an IDE with python plugin in it or using PyCharm will help.

Comment: Read about [`for-else`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Python there is concept `loops with else block:`

- Inside loop execution, if a break statement not executed, then only else part will be
  executed.
- else means loop without a break
- Python allows the `else` keyword to be used with the `for` and `while` loops too. The else `block` appears after the `body of the loop.`

  ```
  for num in range(10):
      if num > 1:
          for i in range(2, num):
              if (num % i) == 0:
                  break
          else:
              print(num)
  ```

Here,
It will print numbers until the `break` statement not executed.